# Using an arduino and python to auto lock my PC

Tags: python, arduino

I use a simple arduino script to control a motion sensor which is either on or off controlled by a button to send a message over serial: 'Motion Detected'. I don't know a lot from python and I used the code below to trigger a batch file that locks my PC. The problem is that when everything is running, if the sensor detects motion and prints the message on serial the batch file gets triggered 3 times so I have to enter my password 3 times. Any solutions to this? Are there better ways of doing it? I use an arduino mega btw.

Arduino Code:

```
int calibrationTime = 30;                               // The time we give the sensor to calibrate (10-60 secs according to the datasheet)
long unsigned int lowIn;                                // The time when the sensor outputs a low impulse      
    
long unsigned int pause = 5000;                         // The amount of milliseconds the sensor has to be low, before we assume all motion has stopped.

boolean lockLow = true;                           
boolean takeLowTime; 
 
const int buttonPin = 6;                                // The digital pin connected to the button input.
int pirPin = 3;                                         // The digital pin connected to the PIR sensors output.
int detectionPin = 34;                                  // The digital pin connected to the LED output.
int armPin = 38;                                        // The digital pin connected to the LED output.
int disarmPin = 36;                                     // The digital pin connected to the LED output.
int buttonState = 0;                                    // Initialize state of button




void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin(9600);                                 // Begin serial communication for python.
    M
    pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);                             // Declare sensor as input.
    pinMode(detectionPin, OUTPUT);                      // Declare LED as output.
    pinMode(armPin, OUTPUT);                            // Declare LED as output.
    pinMode(disarmPin, OUTPUT);                         // Declare LED as output.
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);                   // Declare button as input and use the internal pull up resistor.
    
    digitalWrite(pirPin, LOW);                          // Declare starting state of sensor.                    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < calibrationTime; i++);           // Give the sensor some time to calibrate
  }
 

void loop()
{
      int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);         // Read the state of the pushbutton value.

      if (buttonState == LOW)                           
        {
        digitalWrite(disarmPin, LOW);                   // Turn off the green (safe) LED.
        digitalWrite(armPin, HIGH);                     // Turn on the red (arm) LED.
        if(digitalRead(pirPin) == HIGH)                 
          {
          digitalWrite(detectionPin, HIGH);             // Turn on the blue (detection) LED.
            if(lockLow)
              {
              Serial.println("Motion Detected!");       //Print to serial port for python software detection.
              }
              lockLow = false;                          // Makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made.                               
            takeLowTime = true;
          }
 
        if(digitalRead(pirPin) == LOW)
            {      
            digitalWrite(detectionPin, LOW);            // Turn on the blue (detection) LED.
            if(takeLowTime)
              {
              lowIn = millis();                         //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
              takeLowTime = false;                      //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
              }

              if(!lockLow && millis() - lowIn > pause)  //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause, we assume that no more motion is going to happen
                {      
                lockLow = true;                         //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after a new motion sequence has been detected
                delay(50);
                }
            }  
            
        }
      if (buttonState == HIGH)
        {
          digitalWrite(disarmPin, HIGH);                // Turn on the green (safe) LED.
          digitalWrite(armPin, LOW);                    // Turn off the red (arm) LED.
        }      
}
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
import subprocess
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)

print(ser.name) 

while (True):
    line = ser.readline().decode('UTF-8')

    for char in line:
        subprocess.call([r'D:\00 DATA C\Documents\Arduino Projecten\Autolock PC\runlockpc.bat'])

    ser.close()
```

Comment: In the `for char in line:` loop, what are each of the chars triggering the script? And are there only certain chars you want to trigger it?

Comment: To all the moderators rejecting my suggested edit of the post to remove the apostrophe in code comment so the code highlights correctly, the review page does not render the code highlights in the same way as the question page. Almost the whole code block for the Arduino code is displayed as red text which greatly affects the readable. @Louis, if the moderators reject my edit do you mind removing the apostrophe in your code comment at `// The digital pin connected to the PIR sensor's output.` to fix the code highlights please

Comment: @SuzukiBKing I removed the apostrophe in my code so that the code block wouldn't show up as red.

Answer (score 1):

With serial I found it better to use the `ser.read_all()` command.

```
try:
    line = ''
    while True:
        line += ser.read_all().decode('UTF-8')

        if 'Motion Detected!' in line:
            line = ''
            subprocess.call([r'D:\00 DATA C\Documents\Arduino Projecten\Autolock PC\runlockpc.bat'])

finally:
    ser.close()
```

**Update to exit as per OP comment**

This is a good use-case for the python [while-else](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_while_else.asp) command. *With the else statement we can run a block of code once when the condition is no longer is true*

```
try:
    line = ''
    while 'Motion Detected!' not in line:
        line += ser.read_all().decode('UTF-8')
    else:
        subprocess.call([r'D:\00 DATA C\Documents\Arduino Projecten\Autolock PC\runlockpc.bat'])
finally:
    ser.close()
```

Comment: That's indeed the right code I was searching for, thanks! 1 thing I changed was when the batch file gets triggered, the program closes because each logon on the PC starts the python program.

Comment: Pleasure. For that case I would structure it a little different. I'll update the answer to show that as well. Please click the check-mark to accept the answer if you are happy.